# Remove extra space when handling multiple nodes in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a couple of nodes that contrain track data and I want to concatenate them all in one string that becomes a new variable `$tracks`.

```
    <xsl:template match="tracks">
        <xsl:variable name="trackArtist">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/artists/item/@artist" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="item/concat(@unit, '|', @track, '|null|', @text, '|', $trackArtist, '|null|null|')" />
    </xsl:template>
```

So this works, it concatenates them all. But I had one space at every end of a node, and I tried a lot of things `normalize-space`, `string-join` etc. But then I found out the extra space is just generated by each node that's processed.

```
<tracks>
    <item text="SILENCE" track="1" unit="1"/>
    <item text="HAPPINESS" track="2" unit="1"/>
    <item text="DREAM" track="3" unit="1"/>
</tracks>
```

Result (notice the space behind '|null|null|':

```
1|1|null|SILENCE|FOURPLAY|null|null| 1|2|null|HAPPINESS|FOURPLAY|null|null| 1|3|null|DREAM|FOURPLAY|null|null|
```

**How can I concatenate the data from a node PLUS all the other nodes?**

Comment: Have you tried using an `<xsl:strip-space>` declaration at the beginning of your XSL stylesheet?

Comment: Yep, but I either don't know what element to use or it just doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out with a little help from a colleague.

Since it's a nodelist that you're editing, it will apply the standard built-in way of handling, thus adding a space after each node. So by adding a `string-join()` you can manipulate this. This also fixes the issue of having a trailing (unnecessary) pipe.

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(item/concat(@unit, '|', @track, '|null|', @text, '|', $trackArtist, '|null|null'), '|')" />
```